# Applying CASE WHEN to MIN/MAX

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to apply `MIN/MAX` to my `SELECT` clause based on two criteria. (See Below). When I try to reference my column `submitted_at` in another query, it says the column reference is ambiguous.

```
MIN(CASE WHEN (document != 'dphoto' AND document_type != 'dlicenses' AND 
status = 'upload') THEN occurred_at END) AS submitted_at,`

MAX(CASE WHEN (document_type = 'dphoto' AND document_type = 'dlicenses' AND
status = 'upload') THEN occurred_at END) AS submitted_at`
```

I've attempted to consolidate the phrase into 1 select but have been unsuccessful. Any tips are appreciated

Comment: It's ambiguous because you have columns naming are essentially the same. Why don't you try to change **min_submitted_at** and **max_submitted_at**

Comment: thanks for the help! the above answer worked with what I was trying to accomplish

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two into one column by using the following:

```
CASE    WHEN    (document != 'dphoto' AND document_type != 'dlicenses' AND status = 'upload')
            THEN    Min(occurred_at)
        WHEN    (document_type = 'dphoto' AND document_type = 'dlicenses' AND status = 'upload') 
            THEN    Max(occurred_at)
END As Submitted_at
```

Comment: After doing some additional validation I noticed that it seems like when dphoto and dlicense is `TRUE` the results aren't returned in my query? Is an `OR` statement required?